# $QTDIR refers to wrong directory in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I just met a problem which took another couple of hours.
I've got a project which is depends on `Qt`. I just installed Qt 5.9.1 but errors:

```
E1696   cannot open source file "QDir"  Logger  \Logger.cpp 3   
E1696   cannot open source file "QFile" Logger  \Logger.cpp 4   
E1696   cannot open source file "QString"   Logger  \Logger.cpp 5   
E1696   cannot open source file "QStringBuilder"    Logger  \Logger.cpp 6   
E1696   cannot open source file "QDateTime" Logger  c\Logger.cpp    7   
E1696   cannot open source file "QMessageBox"   Logger  \Logger.cpp 8   
E1696   cannot open source file "QApplication"  Logger  \Logger.cpp 9
```

still appears. Why?

I tried to add include folder to the project with `$(QTDIR)` variable in *Properties Pages*. But it refers not to the directory where I installed Qt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [QTDIR not found error building project in MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139495/qtdir-not-found-error-building-project-in-msvc#11388901) ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11388901/3743145)) I get know the problem is in `*.vcxproj.user`.

---

#### Solution 1.

Find all values of `<QTDIR>` keys in all `*.vcxproj.user` in solutions.
For example with regexp

```
<QTDIR>.*</QTDIR>
```

and replace them with proper Qt directory, i.e.:

```
<QTDIR>C:\\Qt\\Qt5.9.1\\5.9.1\\msvc2017_64</QTDIR>
```

double `\\` is for regexp. *Write single* `\` *if **no** regexp used*.

---

### Solution 2. Better due to its portability

Set environment variable `QTDIR` manually (for current user):

```
> setx QTDIR "C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\msvc2017_64"
```

I think this must be done by Qt Installer. *You also may like `setx /m`.*
Next you should **remove** or rename all `<QTDIR>` keys from `*.vcxproj.user` files. Or **delete** these files at all.

**DONE. Enjoy building the project. Restart MS VS could be required.**

---

#### Note

The `*.vcxproj.user` files should not be transferred to other machines/environments, they belongs current system cinfiguration. So exclude them from your repository, i.e. with `.gitignore`

---

#### **Possible solution 3**

Use **Qt Visual Studio Tools** extension. I did not test this.

Comment: **Qt Visual Studio Tools** is very useful for its Designer. It works just as well with **VS2019**.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similiar problems, thought it was in the properties (from the property manager) at first, but turns out it was not. For me this did the trick:

-Right-click your concerning project in solution explorer and choose "Unload project". Delete the *.user file that belongs to your project.

-Reload the project again by right-clicking it in your solution explorer. Double check that the project configuration is the one you really want (Debug, 64 Bit, etc.)